# How to hide "stage1" after you show "stage2" on a button click [JavaFX]

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I have 2 .fxml files (stage1.fxml and stage2.fxml) and its controller class.

I have a button in stage1.fxml which opens stage2.fxml when clicked, it has this code on it:

```
public void btnStage2(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            Parent stage2 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/stage2.fxml"));
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setScene(new Scene(stage2));
            stage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

this opens `stage2` just fine, however the `stage1` is still open and I can just tab into it and still use the buttons in that stage, and I don't want that.

How can I .setVisible(false) the `stage1` when I press the `btnStage2` just before opening the stage2.fxml?

I found other posts regarding "hiding" the stage instead of closing it when I pressed the close button, but that doesn't match my need. Thanks for the help!

Comment: From the documentation of [Stage#close()](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Stage.html#close()): "_Closes this Stage. This call is equivalent to hide()_". So basically that method is an alias for another—[Window#hide()](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Window.html#hide()): "_Attempts to hide this Window by setting the visibility to false_". Note that Stage extends from Window. So it would seem either of those methods would fit you needs (and I'm guessing that's what those other posts suggested).

Comment: By the way, unrelated to your question, but your `stage2` variable name is misleading. You haven't created a stage but rather the _root_ of a _scene_ which will then be set on a _stage_ (i.e. window).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after hours of trial and error, I think I finally understood how stage.close() works.

the solution to my problem is to just slap these 2 lines of code in the method for the button:

```
Stage stage1= (Stage) btnStage2.getScene().getWindow();
stage1.close();
```

Previously, I thought that I cannot call multiple `Stage` in a single function. Turns out I was wrong.

Comment: "_Previously, I thought that I cannot call multiple Stage in a single function_" – A Stage is just an object like any other. You can reference any number of different instances in the same scope as long as you have a way to differentiate between them (e.g. different variables, a data structure, etc.).